# how to bundle .py files launched with execfile() on py2exe?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I'm developing a small tool on Python which basically launches a set of scripts on a folder. I need to package this on a stand-alone binary and I'm using py2exe for it.

My current code use `os.path.listdir()` to get all the .py files on a folder, and then launch some of them using `execfile()` funcion based on user input on a PyQT interface.

My code works as expected if executed through the main Python file, but fails when compiled with py2exe. The exception is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

for the python files launched with `execfile()`.

I'm currently bundling with `"bundle_files": 1` and `zipfile = None`. I tried to include these files messing with includes and packages but without luck. Can you help me to configure py2exe properly?

This is my current `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os

#Python modules excluded from binary file
mod_excludes = [
    "Tkinter",
    "doctest",
    "unittest",
    "pydoc",
    "pygments",
    "pdb",
    "email",
    "_ssl",
    "difflib",
    "inspect"
]

#Avoid adding this dependencies
dll_excludes = [
    "MSVCP90.dll",
    "w9xpopen.exe"
]

#Force to exe
mod_includes = [
    "sip"
]

package_includes = [
    "app.payloads"
]



py2exe_options = {
    "optimize": 2,  # 0 (None), 1 (-O), 2 (-OO)
    "includes": mod_includes,
    "excludes": mod_excludes,
    "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
    "packages": package_includes,
    #"xref": False,
    "bundle_files": 1,
    "compressed": True
    #"dist_dir": dist_dir
}

#TODO generar automaticamente la interfaz

setup(
    windows=[{"script": "app.py",
        "icon_resources": [(1, "app/gui/Res/app.ico")],
        "uac_info": "requireAdministrator"}],
    data_files=exe_files,
    options={"py2exe": py2exe_options},
    zipfile=None
    )
```

And I'm getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app\gui\ui.pyo", line 22, in call_report
  File "app\core\core.pyo", line 32, in generate_report
  File "app\core\core.pyo", line 18, in launch_payload
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\path\\to\\app\\dist\\app.exe\\app\\payloads\\autoruns.py'
```

Comment: Can you add your `setup.py` code and the output from when you attempt to run this via python/py2exe to the question?

Comment: Thanks Bas! I've added the setup.py and the traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Py2exe only includes `*.pyc` files (or `.pyo` files if you use `"optimize"` greater than 0 as you do). Since you error message mentions a non existing `*.py` file:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'C:\Users\my_user\path\to\app\dist\app.exe\app\payloads\autoruns.py'

, this might be the reason.

In general, I would recommend not to use `execfile()`. Rather write your own package. Py2exe will include this package automatically if you import it somewhere in your application code. This package should contain the files you want to load dynamically. You can use this code:

```
my_module = __import__('my_package.module_name')
```

The string `'module_name'` can come from the user input through the GUI.